# we were unable to access your site's robots.txt file

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-crawlers

I verified my site using google webmaster. I have made my website in Wordpress and I also added robots.txt. Now google is showing green tick mark on DNS and Server Connectivity but and yellow warning mark on robots.txt fetch..

My robots.txt file is look like this:
[robots file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXLIz.png)

Also when I run robots.txt test in webmaster it gives allowed result.. My site is not even being searched in google..

when i submit my site in webmaster that time its not showing error but now its showing.

Please help to slove this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you made your website with wordpress 
It will automatically generate an robots.txt file for you 
Why you Did not use it ?!